# HOW TO: SQL Server select distinct field based on max value in other field

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, max

```
id   tmpname      date_used        tkt_nr
---|---------|------------------|--------|
1  | template| 04/03/2009 16:10 | 00011  |
2  | templat1| 04/03/2009 16:11 | 00011  |
5  | templat2| 04/03/2009 16:12 | 00011  |
3  | diffname| 03/03/2009 15:11 | 00022  |
4  | diffname| 03/03/2009 16:12 | 00022  |
6  | another | 03/03/2009 16:13 | NULL   |
7  | somethin| 24/12/2008 11:12 | 00023  |
8  | name    | 01/01/2009 12:12 | 00026  |
```

I would like to have the result:

```
id   tmpname      date_used        tkt_nr
---|---------|------------------|--------|
5  | templat2| 04/03/2009 16:12 | 00011  |
4  | diffname| 03/03/2009 16:12 | 00022  |
7  | somethin| 24/12/2008 11:12 | 00023  |
8  | name    | 01/01/2009 12:12 | 00026  |
```

So what I'm looking for is to have distinct `tkt_nr` values excluding NULL, based on the max value of datetime.

I have tried several options but always failed

```
SELECT *
FROM  templateFeedback a 
JOIN (
      SELECT ticket_number, MAX(date_used) date_used
      FROM   templateFeedback
      GROUP BY ticket_number
     ) b 
ON a.ticket_number = b.ticket_number AND a.date_used = b.date_used
```

I would appreciate any help. Unfortunately I need the code to be compatible with SQL Server.

Comment: What isn't working with the query you have above?  That seems like it should do it nicely...

Comment: I thought so as soon as i execute it i get:
[link](http://postimage.org/image/frotjpabb/)

Comment: @user1695182 are you in the correct DB? Is the table in a schema that you need to identify?

Comment: The error doesn't appear related to the query structure, but rather to the tablename 'templateFeedback' not being found.  Can you double check that you can run `SELECT * FROM templateFeedback LIMIT 1`?

Comment: table in schema is shortened version of the one I'm using.
here is the full schema: [link](http://postimage.org/image/dmsqsqyjp/)

Comment: wow i feel so retarded now i have just misspelled table name.

Comment: Happens to all of us sometimes :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've stopped doing things this way since I discovered windowing functions. Too often, there are two records with the same timestamp and I get two records in the resultset. Here's the code for tSQL. Similar for Oracle. I don't think mySQL supports this yet.

```
Select id, tmpname, date_used, tkt_nbr
From 
(
    Select id, tmpname, date_used, tkt_nbr,
        rownum = Row_Number() Over (Partition by tkt_nbr Order by date_used desc)
) x
Where row_num=1
```