# Check greater value of row and then take every row with same value grouping by ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've this database:

```
╔═════════╦══════╦══════════╦═══════════╦════╦═════════╗
║ ID_Elab ║ Step ║ ID_Progr ║ ID_Causal ║ GI ║ Minutes ║
╠═════════╬══════╬══════════╬═══════════╬════╬═════════╣
║       8 ║    1 ║        8 ║        19 ║  0 ║     480 ║
║       8 ║    2 ║     1391 ║        19 ║  0 ║     480 ║
║       8 ║    3 ║     1781 ║        19 ║  0 ║     480 ║
║      10 ║    1 ║       10 ║        50 ║  0 ║     480 ║
║      10 ║    1 ║       43 ║        14 ║  0 ║     210 ║
║      10 ║    2 ║       99 ║        50 ║  0 ║     480 ║
║      10 ║    2 ║      100 ║        14 ║  0 ║     210 ║
║      10 ║    3 ║      124 ║        50 ║  0 ║     480 ║
║      10 ║    3 ║      125 ║        72 ║  0 ║     120 ║
║      10 ║    3 ║      126 ║        73 ║  0 ║      90 ║
║      11 ║    1 ║        8 ║        19 ║  0 ║     480 ║
║      11 ║    2 ║     1391 ║        19 ║  0 ║     480 ║
╚═════════╩══════╩══════════╩═══════════╩════╩═════════╝
```

I need to check, for each group of IDs, which is the greater `Step` value and then select every row of the specific group with that `Step` value.

The above table would becomes:

```
╔═════════╦══════╦══════════╦═══════════╦════╦═════════╗
║ ID_Elab ║ Step ║ ID_Progr ║ ID_Causal ║ GI ║ Minutes ║
╠═════════╬══════╬══════════╬═══════════╬════╬═════════╣
║       8 ║    3 ║     1781 ║        19 ║  0 ║     480 ║
║      10 ║    3 ║      124 ║        50 ║  0 ║     480 ║
║      10 ║    3 ║      125 ║        72 ║  0 ║     120 ║
║      10 ║    3 ║      126 ║        73 ║  0 ║      90 ║
║      11 ║    2 ║     1391 ║        19 ║  0 ║     480 ║
╚═════════╩══════╩══════════╩═══════════╩════╩═════════╝
```

I've tried to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570747/how-to-sql-server-select-distinct-field-based-on-max-value-in-other-field) and this is my resulting query:

```
SELECT *
FROM testVela  a
JOIN (
            SELECT ID_Elab, MAX(Step) AS Step, ID_Progr, ID_Causal, GI, Minutes
            FROM testVela 
            GROUP BY ID_Elab, ID_Progr, ID_Causal, Minutes
        ) b
ON a.ID_Elab = b.ID_Elab AND a.Step = b.Step
```

But this query returns something completely wrong... how could I do?

Comment: What is the result ?

Comment: just the original one with every Step value set to the max...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
create table #test_table(
    ID_Elab int,
    Step int,
    ID_Progr int,
    ID_Casusal int,
    GI int,
    Minutes int
)
insert into #test_table
select 8, 1, 8, 19, 0, 480 union all 
select 8, 2, 1391, 19, 0, 480 union all 
select 8, 3, 1781, 19, 0, 480 union all 
select 10, 1, 10, 50, 0, 480 union all
select 10, 1, 43, 14, 0, 210 union all 
select 10, 2, 99, 50, 0, 480 union all 
select 10, 2, 100, 14, 0, 210 union all 
select 10, 3, 124, 50, 0, 480 union all 
select 10, 3, 125, 72, 0, 120 union all 
select 10, 3, 126, 73, 0, 90 union all 
select 11, 1, 8, 19, 0, 480 union all 
select 11, 2, 1391, 19, 0, 480 

;with cte as(
    select
        *,
        rn = rank() over(partition by ID_Elab order by step desc)
    from #test_table
)
select
    ID_Elab,
    Step,
    ID_Progr,
    ID_Casusal,
    GI,
    Minutes
from cte
where
    rn = 1

drop table #test_table
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql> select * FROM tst where step = (select max(step) from tst as B where tst.ID_Elab = B.ID_Elab);
+---------+------+----------+-----------+----+---------+
| ID_Elab | Step | ID_Progr | ID_Causal | GI | Minutes |
+---------+------+----------+-----------+----+---------+
|       8 |    3 |     1781 |        19 |  0 |     480 |
|      10 |    3 |      124 |        50 |  0 |     480 |
|      10 |    3 |      125 |        72 |  0 |     120 |
|      10 |    3 |      126 |        73 |  0 |      90 |
|      11 |    2 |     1391 |        19 |  0 |     480 |
+---------+------+----------+-----------+----+---------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're there already, just need to remove some of the fields.

```
SELECT *
FROM testVela  a
JOIN (
            SELECT ID_Elab, MAX(Step) AS Step
            FROM testVela 
            GROUP BY ID_Elab
        ) b
ON a.ID_Elab = b.ID_Elab AND a.Step = b.Step
```

Answer (score 1):

simple solution

```
select * 
from testVela tbl 
where tbl.Step = (select Max(Step) from testVela   subtbl where subtbl.ID_Elab = tbl.ID_Elab) order by  tbl.ID_Elab
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you will try this

```
select 
    ID_Elab,
    Step,
    ID_Progr,
    ID_Casusal,
    GI,
    Minutes from 
(SELECT rank() over (partition by ID_Elab order by step desc) as rn,*
FROM testVela) as tbl 
where rn=1
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try the code below:

```
create table temp(
        ID_Elab int,
        Step int,
        ID_Progr int,
        ID_Casusal int,
        GI int,
        Minutes int
    )
    insert into temp
    select 8, 1, 8, 19, 0, 480 union all 
    select 8, 2, 1391, 19, 0, 480 union all 
    select 8, 3, 1781, 19, 0, 480 union all 
    select 10, 1, 10, 50, 0, 480 union all
    select 10, 1, 43, 14, 0, 210 union all 
    select 10, 2, 99, 50, 0, 480 union all 
    select 10, 2, 100, 14, 0, 210 union all 
    select 10, 3, 124, 50, 0, 480 union all 
    select 10, 3, 125, 72, 0, 120 union all 
    select 10, 3, 126, 73, 0, 90 union all 
    select 11, 1, 8, 19, 0, 480 union all 
    select 11, 2, 1391, 19, 0, 480 


    select 
        ID_Elab,
        Step,
        ID_Progr,
        ID_Casusal,
        GI,
        Minutes from 
    (SELECT row_number  over (partition by ID_Elab order by step desc) as rn,*
    FROM temp) as tbl 
    where rn=1
    drop table temp
```

Comment: its just copy paste of wewesthemenace query